# Do http calls before DOM is ready Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm using Angular 5 generated with angular-cli.

I want to know how to execute some https call before the DOM is ready and the app it's bootstraped.
I want to do this because the application it's too big (The application is using lazy loading).
In the network request I see a lost time that I can use to make the http calls while the DOM is doing his job.

Here we can see in chrome developers tools, network tab. [Image network](https://ibb.co/c64uLR)

I try to do adding a provider in AppModule like this:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (setup: SetupService) => () => setup.execute(),
  deps: [SetupService],
  multi: true
}
```

And do in main.ts like:

```
setupSerice.setup().then(() => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

But I get the same results.
The setupService do my http calls.

What else can I try or do?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the result you get is that is waits until the service returns before it bootstraps?  What if you call a service that calls the setup service.  This first service can just return the promise after it calls the setup service.  I believe the app will bootstrap as soon as you return the promise.

so something like this:
ServiceCallerService

```
doIt():Promise<any>{
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     this.setupService.execute();
     resolve();
   });
 }
```

the setupService can store your data in a behavior subject and then you can get it when you need it.

Comment: This is what actually do de setupService. With those code I have he same issue.

Comment: what is the setupService.setUp doing?  the app will not bootstrap until that is done in the code above

Comment: It doing the http call, I know the app not bootstrap until the setup ends. But the problem is that the setup it's not being executed until the DOM is ready.